# Calculate the z coordinate of an object relative to the camera with kinect

Tags: camera, coordinates, kinect

I want to calculate the z coordinate of an object relative to the camera (kinect), knowing the information of depth from the kinect. I know also the intrinsic parameters.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What drivers are you using ? (KinectSDK, OpenKinect/libfreenect, OpenNI ?)

Comment: So c++, right ? Are you using OpenCV built with OpenNI support ?

Comment: Yes, I get the depth with: depthMap.at<unsigned short>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the real world measurements (including depth), you want to retrieve the point cloud map, something like:

```
Mat world;
if( capture.retrieve(world, CV_CAP_OPENNI_POINT_CLOUD_MAP)){
Vec3f pt3D = world.at<Vec3f>(yourY, yourX);
cout << "pt3D" << pt3D << endl;
}
```

Notice that you pass the y first, then the x.
I've [learned that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962203/measuring-distance-between-2-points-with-opencv-and-openni) somewhat recently :)

Comment: But cout << "pt3D " << pt3D[2]   give me the same value of depthMap.at<unsigned short> (y,x). Instead, I want the value along the z coordinate camera

Comment: As far as I can tell the OpenNI grabber returns the [x,y,z position in meters](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/modules/highgui/src/cap_openni.cpp?rev=4926#L482) for the POINT_CLOUD_MAP. Is that not what you need ?

Comment: I tried to select two pixels: (310,80) and (310,80) but I had pt3D1[2]=1.014 and pt3D2[2]=1.052 instead they must be the same

Comment: you can try to use putText to draw coordinates in your output image/matrix, but assuming (310,80) is a valid depth pixel and the object in realife at that location doesn't move (nor the kinect), depth values will be around the same, but not exactly the same. From what I hear, if you check a depth value using an Asus sensor, the depth value for the same pixel will remain stable. I haven't experienced that with the kinect though...depth always seems to 'flicker' a bit around a value